# Why am I getting CS0119 using a static method in a template?

Tags: c#

Why does this (contrived) example give "error CS0119: 'T' is a 'type parameter', which is not valid in this context". Surely I have told it that the type will have a suitable method?

```
abstract class Foo
{
   static public bool IsIt() {return true;}
}

class Bar
{
   public bool CanIt<T>() where T : Foo
   {
       return T.IsIt();
   }
}
```

The actual motivating example is something more complicated involving CRTP in the template parameter, but this shows the problem.

Comment: You're not passing it an instance of `T`, you're just passing its type. You can't call a method on something that is there simply to determine the type.

Comment: This does not really make sense. Static methods are not inherited, so your class is never going to return something else but true and in addition, no derivation of Foo is forced to actually have a static member called IsIt. It may not exist at all.

Comment: c# doesn't have templates. It has generics.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, fair point but you know what I mean.

Comment: @nvoigt, do you mean a derivation of Foo could hide the static method in its base? How?

Comment: @Pete Simply by not Implementing it. I think calling the static through a derived class works, but emits a warning. But there is no inheritance. If you constrain T to be Foo, it would always be Foo.IsIt, never a derived class' method. And because of that, it's not possible, because Foo.IsIt would work just as well without somebody mistaking it for working inheritance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C# compiler does not support the invocation of static methods off of type parameters.

Note that there is no value in doing this here.  The call to `IsIt` must be emitted when `CanIt` is compiled.  There is no way of invoking a static method in a virtual dispatch manner  A static method can only be invoked by referring to the type + method directly.  Hence the only thing the compiler could do here would be to emit a call to `Foo::IsIt`.  So why not just call `Foo::IsIt` directly?

Comment: Well, in the actual example the behaviour of the static method will depend on the exact type. But your answer made me realise that I should have used Foo<T>.IsIt(), which seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Absolutely correct about invoking static methods on type parameters

Answer (score 1):

This answer is no news, but I guess you have a design issue here. Even though, this doesn't answer your question...why not go the OOP way? Why use generics when obviously you dont need them here? Why not make this `CanIt` method just a plain OOP method and pass the abstract class as a parameter. Does `IsIt` have to be a static method? Of course, it depends on what you are trying to achieve but I would make it a virtual method so others can override it as well. Again, I sniff design issues

```
abstract class Foo
{
   public virtual bool IsIt() {return true;}
}

class Bar
{
   public bool CanIt(Foo foo)
   {
       return foo.IsIt();
   }
}
```

I believe it makes it simpler and easier to understand. Or perhaps I'm old-fashion...I don't know

Comment: May I draw your attention to "the actual example is something more complicated".

Comment: @Pete feel free to do so, I can always try